# Justifying applying for US visa in a third country

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I am currently a citizen of Russian Federation, but will be applying for a US B-type visa in Germany, because I need to attend a conference in the US in two months and visa waiting time in Russia is 300 days.

Do I need to justify the reason for applying in Germany while taking the interview?
If yes, would the explanation above be enough?

Comment: 300 days wait for a visit visa, are you sure?

Comment: @HankyPanky yes, the official info [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html) says 300 days for Moscow

Comment: That must be a typing mistake

Comment: @HankyPanky: There's been a lot of news lately about deteriorating diplomatic relationships between the US and Russia, including restricting visa services and expelling consular officials.  I would not be surprised if it has caused massive delays in visa wait time.

Comment: But that same table says 39 days for other non immigrant visas, so how come it takes 300 for a visit one? Then for Vladivostok the waiting time is 90 days, why would it be 300 days for the capital

Comment: AFAIK US officials explicitly stated that you can use consulates in other countries as failover.

Comment: @HankyPanky US Consulate in Vladivostok no longer processes visa applications, just as two other US consulates in Russia. There was actually a US consulate in my home city (St. Petersburg), but it was closed last month, which resulted in more waiting time in Moscow.

Comment: I see, 300 days for a visit visa appointment is quite intriguing, but i think that gives you a good enough reason to apply from another country

Comment: @HankyPanky the three streams are separate.  The values are often wildly different.  In Tel Aviv, it's 37 days for visitor visas and 2 days for "all other nonimmigrant visas"; that's a factor of 18.5, while the Moscow factor is only 7.7.

Comment: @HankyPanky [It's not a mistake](https://www.mercurynews.com/2018/04/23/russians-frustrated-by-us-visa-delay/). A consulate was closed, diplomats expelled, and everything has been slowed the hell down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule is that you should apply in your country of citizenship, or your country of residence.  It sounds like in your case both of those are Russia.

However the key word there is "should" - not "must".  Most US consulates will accept applications for visas from people who reside in a different country, although sometimes with additional restrictions (eg, consulates in Canada generally have a longer waiting time for non-CA citizens/residents).

You will need to show proof of your legal status in the country you are applying in (which in your case is likely a Schengen visa and entry stamp so fairly easy to provide).

You may be questioned as to why you are applying in that country, in which case you should tell the truth (especially as the consulate staff will already almost certainly know the answer!)

As a general rule, your chances of having your application rejected and/or put into administrative processing is higher when you apply outside of your home country. This could be due to any number of things, including language issue (both spoken and written) and the potential that you are applying in a different country to try and game the system somehow.  Given your situation there's not really anything you can do to avoid this possibility...

(I've applied for US visas on multiple occasions outside of my country of citizenship/residence and never had a problem - but as is always the case, it depends on your specific situation)